# Argument principle for conjugate of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If I have a holomorphic function $\phi$ and it has N zeros insider a disk $D$. The Argument principle tell us that the integral
$$\int _{\partial D} \frac{d\phi}{\phi}=2\pi i N$$
Can i get a similar result by taking conjugate to $\phi$?
$$\int _{\partial D} \frac{d\bar{\phi}}{\bar{\phi}}=-2\pi i N$$

Comment: What is $D?\,\,$

Comment: it is a disk with radius $R$ centred at origin. $\phi$ has N zeros inside $D$

Comment: Shouldn't you be integrating over the boundary?

Comment: Oh... sorry, it is my mistake, the integration is taken over the boundary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f=u+iv$ is analytic then $\bar f=u-iv$,and according to the CR equations relating the partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$, and $f'$ we have
$$\eqalign{
df&=(u_x+iv_x)dx+(u_y+iv_y)dy=(u_x+iv_x)(dx+idy)=f'(z)\>dz\ ,\cr
d\bar f&=(u_x-iv_x)dx+(u_y-iv_y)dy=(u_x-iv_x)(dx-idy)=\overline{f'(z)}\>\overline{dz}\ .\cr}$$
This shows that your second integral is just the complex conjugate of the first, so that its value is indeed $-2\pi i N$.